# Canvas Inside of React ComponentDidMount redrawn on window resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, canvas, p5.js

I have a canvas (made in p5.js).  When you first load the page, the canvas is drawn in the background using the full window width.  But i have a button that reveals my projects.  The button increases the window height.  The canvas does not update to draw on the extra added height.  The website without the canvas is live at (https://umr.now.sh/).

My Questions:

- How would i go about getting the compnentdidmount to "refresh" or re-draw the canvas to cover the new window size.
- Do i even need to worry about componentdidmount or does p5.js have some sort of function that can help with the problem

  [image]

[image]

```
//homepage.js 

class Index extends React.Component{
    constructor(){ 
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
        this.isLoaded = this.isLoaded.bind(this)
    }
    isLoaded() {
        console.log("Clicked")
        this.setState({
            isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,

        })
    }

    render(){
        let view;
        if (this.state.isLoading){
            view = <div> <Home isLoading={this.state.isLoading} isLoaded={this.isLoaded}/></div>
        } else {
            view = <div> <Project isLoading={this.state.isLoading} isLoaded={this.isLoaded}/></div>
        }
        return(
            <div className="Homepage">
                <div className="Name-social">
                    {view}
                </div>
                <div>
                <SketchLayOut />
                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Index
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about p5.js, but there is an event-listener in JS where you can listen for changes in window size:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

This code should be in `componentDidMount`. In your `handleResize` function that you provide, you can add logic that updates the size of the canvas based on `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. Something like:

```
function handleResize() {
    //you would pass these values to your canvas to update the width/height
    this.setState({
       width: window.innerWidth, 
       height: window.innerHeight
    });

    //etc
}
```

I'm not sure about the internals of p5.js or other parts of your code, so you will need to find out to update the canvas. This will at least get the width/height values you need, however. You should probably also make sure to remove the listener when the component unmounts (so that would be in `componentWillUnmount`)